# Rails 4.1 assets pipeline production, background image path different in two seperate css files after precompile

Tags: asset-pipeline, ruby-on-rails-4.1

I have a rails 4.1.1 application in production, in that i have a fancybox.css file from the gem 'fancybox2-rails', '0.2.8'

In the application.css i have added the file as below.

```
 *= require jquery.ui.datepicker

 *= require jquery.ui.slider

 *= require fancybox

 *= require_tree .

 *= require_self
```

Also in another lockbox.css file i have added it as below

```
*= require jquery.ui.datepicker

*= require jquery.ui.slider

*= require fancybox
```

In production.rb I have added the configuration for additional compiling of the lockbox.css file like this

```
 config.assets.precompile += %w( lockbox.css )
```

My production environment is configured as a subdirectory

www.test.com/v1

www.test.com/v2

The problem is in the lockbox.css file , where the background url path of an background image is different in application.css and lockbox.css

eg in application.css
the path is correct, `v1/assets/my_image.png`

but in lockbox.css
the same path is compiled wrongly as, `v1/my_image.png`

Please explain why this is happening and what can be done to solve this issue.

Comment: You could try to delete `tmp/cache/assets` directory in your production and deploy again. Though that is not a permanent solution.

Comment: i deleted the tmp/cache/assets folder, but now the relative url part is not coming.  The thing that baffles me is that if i download the css file from the site, in that the path is correct, eg: v1/assets/image.png.  but background image is not shown and in firebug its showing asset not found in the path, /assets/image.png, where the relative url path is missing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

put this configuration in your production.rb

```
config.action_controller.relative_url_root = '/your-sub-uri'
```

This will add the sub-uri to the 3rd party gem assets.

i got this configuration from [here](https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails/issues/25)